# does obstacles in front of sound work bidirectional?

Tags: physics

If sound S played in point A reaches point B with volume V, after turning it off in point A and turning the same sound S in point B on, does it reach point A with the same volume V regardless of what obstacles are between? Ignore the noises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is all to do with wave interaction. Wave sources and sinks operate independently of each other, even when waves interact with each other and with the medium through which they travel.

This is more a physics question, however it is highly appropriate to sound.

A very good explanation can be found at:

[http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/py105/WaveInterference.html](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eduffy/py105/WaveInterference.html)

Additional information on "acoustic diodes" can be found here:

https://publishing.aip.org/publications/latest-content/designing-an-acoustic-diode/

Acoustic Diodes are objects that asynchronously affect sound depending on the direction of incidence.

Comment: Nice, this is actually what reciprocity states. If you interchange a source and a receiver the measured transfer function will be identical up to a constant (scaler) in both cases. One minor detail, the second link is "dead".

Comment: thanks for the heads-up - link is updated.